# Create associative array from Foreach Loop PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I have this foreach loop:

```
foreach($aMbs as $aMemb){
    $ignoreArray = array(1,3);
    if (!in_array($aMemb['ID'],$ignoreArray)){ 
        $aMemberships[] = array($aMemb['ID'] => $aMemb['Name']);
    }
}
```

This prints out the right fields but they are arrays inside arrays.  I need the foreach loop to output a simple array like this one:

```
$aMemberships = array('1' => 'Standard', '2' => 'Silver');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to change your $aMemberships assignment

```
$aMemberships[] = $aMemb['Name'];
```

If you want an array

```
$aMemberships[$aMemb['ID']] = $aMemb['Name'];
```

if you want a map.

What you are doing is appending an array to an array.

Comment: Every answer was the same. Had trouble picking one to vote for. +1 for explaining that he was appending an array to an array.

Comment: what if query return id and name how to loop throug so the id and name can settle in one <td value = "id">name</td>

Answer (score 24):

Associative array in foreach statement:

```
foreach($nodeids as $field => $value) {

  $field_data[$field]=$value;

}
```

Output:

```
Array(
$field => $value,
$field => $value
...
);
```

insertion in CodeIgniter:

```
$res=$this->db->insert($bundle_table,$field_data);
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of

```
$aMemberships[] = array($aMemb['ID'] => $aMemb['Name']);
```

Try

```
$aMemberships[$aMemb['ID']] = $aMemb['Name'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Your existing code uses incremental key and uses the array as corresponding value.
To make make `$aMemberships` an associative array with key as `$aMemb['ID']` and value being `$aMemb['Name']` you need to change

```
    $aMemberships[] = array($aMemb['ID'] => $aMemb['Name']);
```

in the foreach loop to:

```
    $aMemberships[$aMemb['ID']] = $aMemb['Name']);
```

Comment: what if query return id and name how to loop through so the id and name can settle in one `<td value = "id">name</td>`

Answer (score 1):

it prints an array of arrays because you are doing so in this line

```
$aMemberships[] = array($aMemb['ID'] => $aMemb['Name']);
```

where you [] after a variable your are indicating to assign the value in a new row of the array and you are inserting an other array into that row

so you can use the the examples the others haver already gave or you can use this method:

```
int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )
```

here is an example that you can find in the api

```
<?php
$stack = array(0=>"orange",1=>"banana");
array_push($stack, 2=>"apple",3=>"raspberry");
print_r($stack);
?>

//prints
Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

You get `key and value` of an associative array in foreach loop and create an associative with key and value pairs.

```
$aMemberships=array();//define array
foreach($aMbs as $key=>$value){
    $ignoreArray = array(1,3);
    if (!in_array($key,$ignoreArray)){ 
        $aMemberships[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

It will give you an expected output:

```
array('1' => 'Standard', '2' => 'Silver');
```

Comment: what if query return id and name how to loop through so the id and name can settle in one `<td value = "id">name</td>`

Comment: For that you should $key value is numeric.

Comment: id is from database.

Comment: put condition to check it before assigning in array.

Comment: gufran bhai im not getting to it

Comment: i have post a question let me send you the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363702/how-to-check-more-then-one-checkbox-if-value-for-each-checkbox-exist-in-database

Comment: Bro, Your question is unclear please update it and mention your problem. what do you want to do?

Comment: i want to show all permission against one role with checkboxes. and also i want to update them if needed. and i have added function.