# How to check more than one checkbox if value for each checkbox exists in database else unchecked

Tags: php, mysql

I have three Table their structure is added down there. i want to show all role on one screen. and when click on one any role it will take you to next screen where (all the permission shown in check boxes) permission that is given to that role checked and other unchecked. and i want to that dynamically, as it can be given and taken by using check boxes. there check boxes should contain role_id and perm_id so it can b use for crud operations.table has many to many relation.

i have the role_id bu using the `isset($_GET['role_id'])` metthod and perm_id by calling a function that will give me the `perm_id`

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['role_id'])) {
$role_id = $_GET['role_id'];
} ?>
```

> user_permission.php page

```
<?php  $row = $role->allPermission($role_id); if(!empty($row)){ 
                     ?>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="datatable-editable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><center>Add</center></th>
                            <th><center>Update</center></th>
                            <th><center>Delete</center></th>
                            <th><center>View</center></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <?php $all_permissions = $permission->allPermissions();
                            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_permissions)) {
                                $perm_id = $row['perm_id'];
                                $check_permission = $permission->checkPermission($role_id,$perm_id);
                            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_permission)){
                                ?>
                                <td><center><input type="checkbox" perm_id="<?php echo $row['perm_id']?>" value="<?php echo $row['permission']?>">  <?php echo $row['permission']?>
                            </center>
                                </td>

                            <?php 

                             }} ?>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <?php foreach ($row as $val) {?>
                            <td> 
                                <?php if ($val['permission'] == 'add' || $val['permission'] == 'update' || $val['permission'] == 'delete' || $val['permission'] == 'view'){ ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $val['id']?>">
                                <?php } else { ?> <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $val['id']?>" > <?php }?>
                            </td> 
                            <?php } ?> 
                             <!-- foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                                            // echo $key . ' => ' . $val." / "; 
                                            echo $key['prem'];
                                        } -->
                          <!--   <td>   
                                <?php if (in_array('add', $row)){ ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $id?>">
                                <?php } else { ?> <input type="checkbox" > <?php }?>
                            </td>
                            <td>   
                                <?php if (in_array('update', $row)){ ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                                <?php } else { ?> <input type="checkbox" > <?php }?>
                            </td>
                            <td>   
                                <?php if (in_array('delete', $row)){ ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                                <?php } else { ?> <input type="checkbox" > <?php }?>
                            </td>
                            <td>   
                                <?php if (in_array('view', $row)){ ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                                <?php } else { ?> <input type="checkbox" > <?php }?>
                            </td> -->

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

> allPermissions()

```
    public function allPermissions()
{

    $query="SELECT * from permission where status = 1";
    $conn=$this->Connection();

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows>0) {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

> chechkPermission()

```
public function checkPermission($role_id,$perm_id)
{
    $query = "select * from role_perm rp where role_id = '$role_id' and perm_id = '$perm_id' ";
    $conn=$this->Connection();

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows>0) {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

its been three(now) days i'm stuck here, **please help**. and sorry for my bad english

> Table Structure

[image]

> This is how i want it

[image]

Comment: What is your  question?

Comment: :) sorry for that. question is. check boxes checked if they have the permission else unchecked

Comment: That's still not a question

Comment: im sorry then i'm new to php

Comment: Questions begin with one of the following: who, what, why, how, and when

Comment: i have update the title, i hope now it become question

Comment: @AliRaza, Your question is unclear, Please update it.

Comment: @AliRaza, where is allPermissions() and sql query?

Comment: i have addedd it in questiom

Comment: @AliRaza, As I understood your problem.
You are trying to get all permissions against each role. If you check/uncheck checkbox it should also save into database against that role.
Is this your problem right?

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this? `<input type="checkbox" <?= ($permission >= 3 ? "checked" : "") ?>`

Comment: i have add the pic under the table structure please have a look

Comment: im sorry but can you please point out the **specific** problem